# snap remove: operation not permitted

Tags: snap

I have a problem remove a snap package.

```
$ snap list
Name                    Version                 Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
canonical-livepatch     8.1.0                   54    stable    canonical✓  -
core                    16-2.37.1               6350  stable    canonical✓  core
gnome-3-26-1604         3.26.0                  74    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-characters        3.30.0                  139   stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-logs              3.30.0                  45    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-system-monitor    3.30.0                  57    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes       0.1-4-g88bc1b2          818   stable/…  canonical✓  -
microk8s                v1.13.1                 354   stable    canonical✓  desactivado,classic
slack                   3.3.7                   11    stable    slack✓      classic
```

If I want to remove microk8s, I get the following message

```
$ sudo snap remove microk8s
[sudo] contraseña para sogeking: 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Eliminar datos para el snap "microk8s" (354) (remove /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/f04d46763b67891f310ff06bb39c280f5bae5584caa3fab1bfcf0de374aca88a: operation not permitted)
```

Other packages are not locked like this one. What can I do? Thanks.

EDIT: adding extra output

```
$ snap logs microk8s
error: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/logs?n=10&names=microk8s: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
$ sudo ls -l /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/f04d46763b67891f310ff06bb39c280f5bae5584caa3fab1bfcf0de374aca88a
total 0
$ snap services
Service                                   Startup      Current   Notes
canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd  activado     activo    -
microk8s.daemon-apiserver                 desactivado  inactivo  -
microk8s.daemon-apiserver-kicker          desactivado  inactivo  -
microk8s.daemon-controller-manager        desactivado  inactivo  -
microk8s.daemon-docker                    desactivado  inactivo  -
microk8s.daemon-etcd                      desactivado  inactivo  -
microk8s.daemon-kubelet                   desactivado  inactivo  -
microk8s.daemon-proxy                     desactivado  inactivo  -
microk8s.daemon-scheduler                 desactivado  inactivo  -
```

Comment: Can you run and add the output? 

`$ snap logs microk8s`

(Sorry the formatting is a bit weird with comments. There are 3 separate commands here)

`$ sudo ls -l /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/f04d46763b67891f310ff06bb39c280f5bae5584caa3fab1bfcf0de374aca88a`

`$ snap services`

Comment: @RyanJ.Yoder there is the extra logging information. That directory is empty. Thanks!